# Some commands do run with PHP exec() others don't, how can I avoid/fix this?

Tags: php, linux

- Server is CentOS, I don't have root access.
- I can run exec() without problem with `pngquant` but not with ImageMagick's `convert`
- I get "Permission denied" when trying to open the image file with `convert` but works fine with `pngquant` (notice that both commands open same image file in same folder, same permissions, same user, etc).
- Since I don't have root access, I've built ImageMagick and added it to the PATH.
- From command line `convert` works perfect (user has enough privileges to read/write the image files).
- PHP tries to run `exec('convert ...')` or `shell_exec('convert ...')` as nobody, this means `echo shell_exec('whoami');` returns "nobody". Same for `pngquant` but with successful result (no "Permission denied" problem).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I don't have root access, I've built ImageMagick and added it to
>   the PATH.

What are the permissions on the binary you created? Sounds like you—as the user—have rights to execute the binary. But PHP—who is running as `nobody`—does not have execution rights. I bet your binary permissions for what you created are something like `744` or maybe even `700`? I would recommend `chmod 755` on the binaries you created and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and they all are 755. Just FYI ImageMagick install documentation provides a way to build and install the program in a custom path if you don't have root access, I installed ImageMagick that way.  
Another clue is: if I upload the image with FTP, `convert` works fine, but if I upload same image with a HTML form + PHP, I get same issue "Permission denied" when trying to open the file.

Comment: When uploaded, both with FTP or thru HTML form, the file has 644 permissions. The difference I see is that with FTP user/group is "myuser/myuser" and when using HTML form is "nobody/nobody" (nothing strange)

Comment: If it helps, pngquant has user/group "root/root" whereas convert has "myuser/myuser"

Comment: Many thanks @JakeGould, I'm still fighting with it, I'll see if I can change permissions of the files with exec() before using `convert`. Also considering chmod myself to 777 and wait for someone to delete me from the world (?).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I finally could talk an administrator into installing PHP ImageMagick extension. Working great and no more `exec()`s. I bumped into this post by chance after a long time, and wanted to add this comment.